# How to enable httpsrc plug-in in my gstreamer?

Tags: c, http, plugins, gstreamer

I've tried to play an mp3 file or stream retrieved via http with the following command

```
gst-launch httpsrc location=http://domain.com/music.mp3 ! mad ! osssink
```

but a get the following error

```
ERREUR : le pipeline n'a pas pu être construit : pas d'élément « httpsrc ».
```

Which says that the pipeline could not be constructed due to the missing of `httpsrc` element.

After googling around I did not found how to enable/install `httpsrc` plug-ins

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer-httpsrc
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-httpsrc
```

without success.

I'm using the default gstreamer installation which came with my `Ubuntu 12.0.4` distribution.

Do i missing something or Is there any other way to do the same work even witout `httpsrc`

thanks for any reply !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you want to use is called souphttpsrc. You can run gst-inspect | grep http to see all installed elements matching http.

Comment: may be I miss comething while using It because the following command doesn't work `gst-launch souphttpsrc location=https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3t8s9z1g1au0sb/xmas-songs-end-act4-lyon.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink`

Comment: This mp4 file is not streamable (moov atom order). You first need to download it to be able to play it.

Comment: When configure script under gst-plugins-good is executed, type: --enable-soup