# gstreamer0.10 filesrc element cannot find file

Tags: gstreamer-0.10

I want to analyse a mp4 video by:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=file:~/examples/fullstream.mp4 ! tsparse ! tsdemux ! queue ! ffdec_h264 max-threads=0 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink name=video
```

or

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=http://192.168.40.228:8080/fullstream.mp4 ! mpegtsdemux ! queue ! ffdec_h264 max-threads=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink name=video
```

But the terminal shows:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Resource not found.
Additional debug info:
gstfilesrc.c(1042): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
No such file "file:/home/zhaozhenjie/examples/fullstream.mp4"
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The `~/examples/fullstream.mp4` does exist. So I want to ask what's wrong with the code? I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use filesrc for network stream. For http serving file you have to use [souphttpsrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276657/3876138) - it was available also in [GStreamer 0.10](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-good-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-good-plugins-souphttpsrc.html)

```
gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.40.228:8080/fullstream.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

**UPDATE**

This is for using filesrc - the format of path is just normal absolute path or relative path from place where you execute (if needed use double " around):

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/home/user/examples/fullstream.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

This should maybe also work..

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/examples/fullstream.mp4 ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But `location=http://192.168.40.228:8080/fullstream.mp4` in the second script is not what I really mean, and I cannot edit now. I put my file in my home folder `~/examples/fullstream.mp4`, but filesrc shows it does not exist.